# Using Java Script prototype Function in a google sheets external Library

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, prototype

I added a prototype function to `String` in google sheet project, and created a new version to be referenced in another project.
Then I referenced this new library version in another project (Resources-> Libraries in the script editor).
Now I want to use this function, but execution fails as it doesn't recognized this func.

**Function definition in project1:**

```
if (!String.prototype.newStringFunc) {
  String.prototype.newStringFunc = function() {
    Logger.log(this.toString());

  };
}
```

**Usage in Project2:**

```
function test()
{
  var s = "Hello";
  s.newStringFunc();
}
```

**Result:**

> TypeError: s.newStringFunc is not a function

If the function is defined in Project2 - all good.

Other "regular" functions within Project1, are recognized and executed properly.

Is it not possible to add a prototype function to an external library?

Comment: Don't know the answer to that specific question, but extending native prototypes with custom functions is rarely needed. Why not just have a function that takes the string as argument if normal functions work just fine?

Comment: @FelixKling I understand that and your suggestion is always an option. Yet, I wanted to try this. In this case it is a native object, but it does have to be a native object like String. I am obtaining some JS abilities, and this is part of my learning. Also, You can claim that to all prototype functions (using a regular functions instead), isnt it?

Comment: the first part of code is not being executed in the second project, otherwise everything is fine. u can't add a external function 'Globally'. It has to be defined in the project...

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh Not sure I understand. Does **external function** refer to prototype function?

Comment: when u Extend a class using something like this "String.prototype.newStringFunc", this new function is defined in your eco system. so if u defined this function in Project1 and if it is not defined in Project2, how javascript runtime in project2 will know that "String" has a new function

Comment: Where is this line `if (!String.prototype.newStringFunc) {`? Inside a function?

Comment: It seems [String] is not [shared](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries?hl=en)

Comment: @TheMaster `if (!String.prototype.newStringFunc)` It is not inside a function. Just like any other statement at the script global scope.

Comment: @TheMaster where do you see String is not shared, in this link?

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh that is a good question. Maybe I am wrong, and don't understand JS enough. Isn't it just like any other "include" or reference in other languages? when referencing an external library , this library is loaded when execution starts or first use thus, exposing everything to its client?

Comment: My testing seems to suggest that. The link shows the differences between shared and not shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype libraries used to work on old Rhino javascript interpreter.

So, if you turn your ***Project2*** back to old Rhino javascript interpreter for ***project1***, it doenst matter.
It will work again.

Just Go to Menu >> Execute >> Disable Chrome V8.

I don't really know for how long the old interpreter will be available, until then, lets use it.